# display:none vs visibility:hidden vs text-indent:9999 How screen reader behave with each one?

Tags: css, accessibility, screen-readers

What is the difference between these three for screen reader users?

Comment: I have SOME experience with screen readers, although limited, but I would think they ignore CSS... do modern screen readers also ignore javascript generated content?

Comment: JAWS (http://www.freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp), the most popular screen reader (http://www.webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey2/) isn't a dedicated browser, but an application that makes other programs, such as browsers, accessible. I don't know exactly how it works, but I presume it just piggy-backs on the browser's rendering engine to decide what to say.

Comment: Why would you want a hidden text to be read out?. Is it know whats hidden? I am trying to understand application of this CSS property better so you know which one to use when.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

refer: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=ScreenreaderVisibility

**display:none:**  will not be seen nor heard. *
**visibility: hidden:**  will not be seen nor heard. *
**text-indent: 9999:**  will not be seen but it will be heard.

- Most of the screen reader will not 'speak' *display:none* and *visibility: hidden* , but there are few screen readers like [pwWebSpeak](http://www.soundlinks.com/pwgen.htm) and HtReader which will read even these too.

Comment: I tested with NVDA screen reader and it reads those elements which is hidden by display:none

Comment: There is a similar comment in the link i have specified. RTIMO.

Comment: The above possibility is not working with JAWS in IE

Answer (score 18):

There's good explanation about this in A List Apart. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fir/
It depends on product.

```
PRODUCT                         DISPLAY: NONE       VISIBILITY: HIDDEN
Hal version 5.20                Does not read       Reads
IBM Home Page Reader 3.02       Does not read       Does not read
Jaws (4.02, 4.50, 5.0 beta)     Reads               Reads
OutSpoken 9                     Does not read       Does not read
Window-Eyes 4.2                 Does not read       Does not read
```

Please note that this article is from 2003, and the last change to that page on ALA was 2004. Things have changed. The WebAIM page was last updated in 2019: https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/

Comment: What about NVDA`?

Answer (score 11):

There's a very good summary of how screen readers interpret these properties at [WebAIM](http://www.webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/).

In a nutshell, `visibility: hidden` and `display:none` will hide text from screen readers just like it does from others. All other methods will be 'visible' to a screen reader.

Comment: But i downloaded NVDA screen reader software and it reads display:none content

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately screen readers are as inconsistent as sighted browsers when it comes to CSS. The standard is as described above, but there will always be a few that ignore standards.

Comment: I find that NVDA screen reader doesn't read out `display: none` content if it is in that state when the screen loads; but if javascript is used to change the state to `display: none` the screen reader doesn't realise, and reads out the content.

Answer (score 4):

There are [many techniques](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility) to hide content visually but have it available for screen readers.

The H5BP technique works in FF, Webkit, Opera and IE6+

```
.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: damn that explains why i saw this exact snippet on someone s css code, wish they would atleast comment

Answer (score -1):

Complete Answere is here to make sure chrome doesnt autoshow/autofill input boxes.
On my web page ( New User) , telephone field and Password fioeld were being autofilled with cached data. To get rid of this, I created two dummy fields and gave them a class which makes them invisible to the user. A jquery function to show and then hide these after a fraction.

Jquery function to show & hide:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $(".fake-autofill-fields").show();
    // some DOM manipulation/ajax here
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $(".fake-autofill-fields").hide();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Class:

```
.fake-autofill-fields
{ 

     border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px; 
}
```

Input fields:

```
<input style="display:none" type="text" class="fake-autofill-fields" name="fakeusernameremembered"/>
<input style="display:none" type="password" class="fake-autofill-fields" name="fakepasswordremembered"/>
```

Comment: Input fields:
<input style="display:none" type="text" class="fake-autofill-fields" name="fakeusernameremembered"/>
                    <input style="display:none" type="password" class="fake-autofill-fields" name="fakepasswordremembered"/>

Comment: autocomplete="off" ?!