# jquery ui autocomplete adding a span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery autocomplete on a div but I am getting this extra span added automatically by jquery

```
"<span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">search test</span>"
```

How can I prevent this span from being created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's for accessibility reason, blind people can 'read' how much results are find. If you really want to delete this, you can modify the source code:

```
this.liveRegion = $( "<span>", {
                role: "status",
                "aria-live": "polite"
            })
            .addClass( "ui-helper-hidden-accessible" )
            .insertAfter( this.element );
```

But it's not recommended.

Comment: for blind people, 'read' actually means 'listen', by some tools :)

Comment: In addition to screen-reader software applications that converts text to synthesized speech, there are Braille displays which show a page 40 (or 80) characters at a time, sequentially. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refreshable_Braille_display

Answer (score 43):

I solved it by adding a CSS rule:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { display: none; }
```

Comment: this worked for me. i have a question around why this happens (why this span shows up and becomes visible containing the autocomplete returned values)?  it just happened to me suddenly. It didn't happen before.

Comment: Maybe it's because you upgrade jQuery UI to newer version.

Comment: I've just upgraded to the latest JQ versions including the UI and it started after I upgraded. Oddly, the older version i was working with didn't do this.

Comment: For those using Bootstrap 3 who wish to keep the intended functionality, add ```.ui-helper-hidden-accessible{@extend .sr-only;}``` to your framework_and_overrides.css.scss file. There is probably something similar in Foundation now as well...

Answer (score 1):

I was using CSS flex box for layout with nth-child selectors, so, this span distorted my column layout.

`display: none` or `position: absolute; top: -999999` won't resolve my problem. I had to remove the element from the DOM altogether, so, I wrote the following [create event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-create) handler:

```
create: function (e)
{
    e.target.parentElement.removeChild(e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of it by adding this event handler to your autocomplete:

```
$(element).autocomplete({
    ...
    create: function (e) {
        $(this).prev('.ui-helper-hidden-accessible').remove();
    }
});
```

There's no harm in removing it unless you care about blind people accessing our page. I tried the `display: none` trick but that didn't work for me.

Comment: it's not strange for people to care for blind or otherwise disabled ones. So there is harm if you do it, even if you don't care

Comment: It's a contextual issue and, in many cases, it makes sense to not care about providing support that will never be requested in the first place, like in an app requiring visual dexterity.

Answer (score 0):

you really shouldn't remove this (do you want to browse a web page which is only for blind people and you can't access the content?)...

it is not easy to make a website ada compliant.
this span is just a very little piece of all that stuff.

hiding elements with display none or so is a bad practice regarding ada.
that's why pages like facebook hide some elements by indenting them to somewhere off-screen:

[display:none vs visibility:hidden vs text-indent:9999 How screen reader behave with each one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755656/displaynone-vs-visibilityhidden-vs-text-indent9999-how-screen-reader-behave-w)

for ada related stuff you could start here:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/creating-an-ada-compliant-website/

maybe forcing the height to 0 might be of use in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Adding .css file worked for me (and of course removing all span elements worked too, but that is not a good solution):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Answer (score -3):

This will Work Perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("span").remove(); });
```

Comment: you will remove all span elements into `HTML DOM` with this answer