# jQuery UI Autocomplete Widget returning values that populate a span with ui-helper-hidden-accessible class

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have an autocomplete search field that returns the latitude and longitude of a city being searched.

For some reason, on "select" of a suggested result, there is a span with a class of "ui-helper-hidden-accessible" and role of "status" that goes from hidden to visible and shows the selected value of the result.

It is weird because even if I comment out the last line of code that tells "select" event to populate another hidden text field with a returned value from the autocomplete, this "hidden" span still becomes visible with the returned autocomplete value.

What is going on???

This is my Coffeescript for reference

```
    myGeocodeAutocomplete = ->   
  $('[type="text"][name*="[geocode_location]"]').autocomplete
    source: (request, response) ->
      $.ajax 
        url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON"
        dataType: "jsonp"
        data: 
          featureClass: "P"
          style: "full"
          maxRows: 12
          name_startsWith: request.term

        success: (data) ->
          response $.map(data.geonames, (item) ->
            label: item.name + ((if item.adminName1 then ", " + item.adminName1 else "")) + ", " + item.countryName
            value: item.lat + ", " + item.lng
          )
    minLength: 2

    open: ->
      $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass "ui-corner-top"
    close: ->
      $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass "ui-corner-all"
    focus: (event, ui) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      $(this).val ui.item.label      
    select: (event, ui) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      $(this).val ui.item.label
      $(this).siblings('[name*="[geocode_ll]"]').val ui.item.value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer here: [jquery ui autocomplete adding a span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791984/jquery-ui-autocomplete-adding-a-span)

I apologize for asking again but it was a hard and obscure question to look for at the time.