# Autocomplete widget in a td field which has contenteditable

Tags: jquery, wordpress, autocomplete, html-table

I want to use the Autocomplete Widget from http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source .
They wrote I can use it with contenteditable, but it doesnt work.
I also use it in wordpress. So maybe this would be the error.
I get this error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/.../css/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png"
```

But I also included this:

```
wp_enqueue_script("quizEditorScript", plugins_url('js/quizEditor.js', QDB_PATH."qdbConnect"), array('jquery-ui-autocomplete', 'jquery-ui-dialog'));
```

My table looks like this:

```
<table id = "quiz_table">
...
"<td class = 'cate'  contenteditable = 'true' tabindex = '"+tabId+"'>"+cate+"</td>" +
"<td class = 'diff'  contenteditable = 'true' tabindex = '"+tabId+"'>"+diff+"</td>" +
...
```

I want to use autocomplete on the "cate".

```
var availableTags = ["AAA"];
        //jQuery.fn.val = jQuery.fn.html; //Im not sure how to use this
        jQuery(".cate").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
```

Do I have to add some more details or do I have to do it in an other way ?

Comment: View source and check if the script is added.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.menu.min.js?ver=1.10.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.10.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js?ver=1.10.3'></script>

Comment: I had this problem:
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791984/jquery-ui-autocomplete-adding-a-span
I solved it now