# changing content depending on different media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

This is the second attempt at this question as I have worked on this since I last asked so hopefully I'll make more sense this time.

I'm creating a responsive layout for my coming soon page. The main body header changes depending on the size of the browser and the device.

```
 <h1><span class="main__header--changer">COMING SOON</span></h1>
```

... and the CSS

```
 @media (max-width: 75em) {
      h1:before {
           content: "HOLD ONTO YOUR HATS";
      }
      .main__header--changer {
           display: none;
      }
 }

 @media (max-width: 64em) {
      h1:before {
           content: "NOT LONG TO GO";
      }
      .main__header--charger {
           display: none;
      }
 }
```

... and so on and son on, the different variations of coming soon contains less letters as the size goes down, right down to 'nigh'.

The only thing my way of doing this means that screen readers wont read the heading because of the display:none. Is there a different way to hide the heading but not from screen readers but that the content is shown from the css?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use JavaScript ? Or hide the div-s and on certain point show them (`display:block/none;`)?

Comment: I'm trying to just use HTML and CSS if I can as I'm not too confident with javascript. Yeah, I suppose putting the different headings in divs will work, didn't really think of that. Cheers

Comment: Just thought though the source code will look hacky. That was the reason I chose to use content: "" in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a hidden effect by bumping the content way outside the screen display area using margins or the text-indent property. These methods aren't what I'd call 100% clean, but they at least keep your HTML markup tidy.

Check out this [helpful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755656/displaynone-vs-visibilityhidden-vs-text-indent9999-how-screen-reader-behave-w) that explains screen reader interactions with CSS-hidden elements.

I also assume that in the second reference in your CSS you mean `--changer` not `--charger`.

On a side note, if the statement: `.main__header--changer {display: none;}` is the same across  all your media queries, you should consider just writing it once outside of any queries so it applies universally without duplication in your code.

Hope this has been helpful!

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when I indent the h1 it also pulls the div:before content: with it too. Isn't there anything I could do with overflow:hidden for the H1? Yeah, it's meant to be changer. The link is useful thanks.

Comment: You could probably set the H1’s height property to 0, then set overflow to hidden instead of bumping the content offscreen.

Comment: Oh... upon further reading, it looks like screen readers will often ignore content with 0-width/height. I recommend circumventing this by setting width & height to 1px (and increasing line-height if any text happens to land in that 1px space).

Comment: That's it!!!! Thanks Kevin. The :content is now showing while visually hiding "coming soon". So now the screen reader will always read "coming soon" but the heading will visually change for people with eye sight. Also the source code looks clean.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that worked. I hadn't had a chance to test, so I'm glad I wasn't giving bad advice. :) All the best—