# Incorrect usage of AIRA input fields names with select and options

Tags: php, html, laravel

Hello I can't figure out how to manage `this` fields to fix the issue `ARIA input fields do not have accessible names`. When I test website it shows me `this` fields. Any advices?

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <select class="custom-select-box select2 " name="mainCatID"  id="category">
                                <option value="">@lang('language.HEADING_SELECT_CATEGORY')</option>
                                @foreach ($RecipeMainCategory as $val)
                                <option value="{{ base64_encode(base64_encode($val->id)) }}">
                                    {{ $val->category_name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <select class="custom-select-box select2 " name="subCatID" id="sub_category">
                                <option value="">@lang('language.HEADING_SELECT_SUB_CATEGORY')</option>
                                @foreach ($RecipeSubCategory as $val)
                                <option value="{{ base64_encode(base64_encode($val->id)) }}">
                                    {{ $val->category_name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

I have tried to put `label for` before select with status `display:none`, but still received error for `this` fields.

**Edit**:
I checked and maybe it's not an issue from the php side maybe it's coming from jquery-ui.js

```
_drawButton: function() {
        var that = this;

        // Associate existing label with the new button
        this.label = $( "label[for='" + this.ids.element + "']" ).attr( "for", this.ids.button );
        this._on( this.label, {
            click: function( event ) {
                this.button.focus();
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        // Hide original select element
        this.element.hide();

        // Create button
        this.button = $( "<span>", {
            "class": "ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all",
            tabindex: this.options.disabled ? -1 : 0,
            id: this.ids.button,
            role: "combobox",
            "aria-expanded": "false",
            "aria-autocomplete": "list",
            "aria-owns": this.ids.menu,
            "aria-haspopup": "true"
        })
            .insertAfter( this.element );

        $( "<span>", {
            "class": "ui-icon " + this.options.icons.button
        })
            .prependTo( this.button );

        this.buttonText = $( "<span>", {
            "class": "ui-selectmenu-text"
        })
            .appendTo( this.button );

        this._setText( this.buttonText, this.element.find( "option:selected" ).text() );
        this._resizeButton();

        this._on( this.button, this._buttonEvents );
        this.button.one( "focusin", function() {

            // Delay rendering the menu items until the button receives focus.
            // The menu may have already been rendered via a programmatic open.
            if ( !that.menuItems ) {
                that._refreshMenu();
            }
        });
        this._hoverable( this.button );
        this._focusable( this.button );
    },
```

Comment: One simple way is to just use a `<label>`, and either surround the field or use `for` and `id`. Otherwise, you can add ARIA-specific attributes: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.1/aria-input-field-name

Comment: yes i try by adding arria- in select and div but still when i try scan the website shows error so i do it wrong. I present the code clean so you can suggest me how to make it correct

Comment: `display:none` will hide things from accessible readers, too, btw. Checkout out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130500/231316). It is a verbose way to hide things from visual users will still being part of the accessibility tree. Or, consider just showing the label to everyone, sighted and non-sighted, and then everything just works.

Comment: i have updated main question, i think the issue is coming from js side maybe for this 2 buttons

Comment: What tool are you using to find these a11y issues? If you are using JS to update the DOM, it is possible that your tool doesn’t support that, or that the JS is firing after the tool has captured the DOM state.

Comment: im using pagespeed.web.dev

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as i make tests as i figured it out the issue is coming from the js file itself
by adding "aria-label": this.ids.menu, fixed the issue with the error

Comment: shouldn't it be 'aria-label' ?? kindly check and consider reposting your answer

Comment: thanks for the correction my mistake in typing