# Android ICS browser fixed header style disappearing

Tags: android, html, css, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-browser

I'm finding an odd bug in the Android ICS browser, both on my Skyrocket device and in the emulator. Basically the fixed header I have is losing almost all of it's styling (reverting to text though still fixed it appears). This appears to occur when there is a PJAX transition or on certain pages (even though the header HTML and CSS is the same in all cases).

You can see this on a staging environment I've set up:
https://tt-chnicola.herokuapp.com/
User: testuser
Password: password

Just navigate around a bit and you can see what I mean.

Update: To be specific I'm using 4.0.3 (API level 15) and my phone is 4.0.4 from Samsung

Also occurs on 4.0 (API 14)

It works fine on GB (API 10) and JB (API 16) so this seems to be an ICS exclusive problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this does appear to be a browser bug, but it was fixable by removing a floated "image replacement" element that was using a technique similar to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/471538/235243

Looks like the text that was being hidden was coming up and pushing the entire header out of view for some reason.