# Hide text in H1 tag but not the image

Tags: html, css, hide

I need to hide the text inside a H1 tag. But not the image.
Problem is that i only can change the css and not the html

```
<h1>
<img src="img/headerimg.png" width="900" height="125"/>
Header 1 text
</h1>
```

Is there a way to only hide the "Header 1 text" with only css?
I'm doing this for big client and they gave me only acces to the css file.

Comment: _Very_ hacky, but you could set the text colour to the background colour?

Comment: You could try change the color of the text the whatever the background color is.

Comment: the background is a texture :(

Comment: Setting css `color` property to `transparent` should work

Comment: I provided a one line CSS based answer that doesn't require touching the markup at all.

Comment: use `text-indent: -999em;` this will help screen readers to read the text instead of using `display: none;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide text using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471510/hide-text-using-css)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give a 0px font size

```
​h1{ font-size:0px }​
```

Edit: Working [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/qtX9n/)

Comment: In Opera Browser the text is still visible, very small but still visible.

Comment: ​h1{ font-size:0px; color: rgba(0,0,0,0) }​
This will also make the font invisibile. The element is still in the DOM and has an effect on other surrounding images. The only good solution is to change HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Set the image as background of the `<h1>`, add CSS properties to the `<h1>` to make it the size of the image and use a negative `text-indent` on the headline to remove the text. That would be the usual and ideal way to do it if you had access to the html too.

Since you only have access to the CSS, you can use this:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 0.1px; /* 0 gets disregarded by Internet Explorer, 0.1 gets interpreted right by every browser */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VGgnD/

Comment: but the img tag will still be in the markup.  As the OP said, he only has access to the CSS file, so you will have to additionally hide the image too.

Comment: @thescientist use `H1 img { display: none} `

Comment: right, that's what I was getting at.  But Markus might want to update his answer to meet all the OP's requirements.

Comment: I added a completely different approach, in the end it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

#### You can do this way using CSS:

```
<h1>
    <img src="img/headerimg.png" width="900" height="125"/>
    Header 1 text
</h1>
```

#### CSS:

```
h1 {
    width: 900px;
    height: 125px;
    background: url("img/headerimg.png") no-repeat center center;
    text-indent: -99em;
}
```

If you have access only to CSS, please `display: none;` the `img`:

```
h1 img {display: none;}
```

#### Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sJ8JD/

Comment: he has an access **only** to CSS as he said

Comment: @haynar Fixed. Done. Added fiddle.! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well the only thing that comes to my mind is this:

```
<h1 style="color: transparent; font-size: 0px; text-indent: -99em;">
<img src="http://pokit.org/get/img/18d5148ef77ef2a2d5d8193c1c8789e8.jpg" width="900" height="125"/>
Header 1 text
</h1>
```

Working example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/VRQVs/2/

Answer (score 0):

set `font-size: 1px !important;` and set background color as text color

Comment: The text is visible like flycrap then, but still visible.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer even with the same color as background?

Comment: Depends on what the background is. Maybe it's an animated gif? :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try `position:absolute;` so the text won't be visible, it will be positioned outside the page. `-5000px`

```
h1 {
  margin-top:-5000px;
  position:absolute;
}
h1 img {
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:5000px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2UeHD/)

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as setting the font-size to 0px

```
h1 {
   font-size: 0.1px;
}
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/m5V2A/](http://jsfiddle.net/m5V2A/1/)

Comment: Lol yeah, text is selectable! :P

Comment: Lolz, my work is to fix IE bugs in my office! :( Think of my situation! That too for enterprise applications! It is... ... ew...