# Hide element's text with CSS

Tags: html, css

Im [trying](http://jsfiddle.net/hbHnW/) to hide text (that I use for screenreaders) in an `a` tag and instead use a background icon.

HTML

```
<a href="#"><span>Search</span></a>
```

CSS

```
span {
    display: none;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 17px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c3zk.png);
}
```

Is there a way to do the same without `span`?

Comment: I guess you add title to your anchor tag and your screen reader would read the same. For almost all the elements you can add this attribute and make it readable.

Comment: You're welcome SakerONE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indent the text so it's completely off the screen:

```
text-indent:-5000px;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a screenreader software but if I guess right this should work:

```
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c3zk.png" alt="Search" /></a>
```

With this css rule:

```
a img {
    border:0;
}
```

Basically the `alt` attribute is the alternative text, which should be used in case of a screen reader.

Answer (score 2):

You should check: [Hide text using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471510/hide-text-using-css)

But it goes like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Search</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    white-space: nowrap;  
    outline: none;

    display: inline-block;
    width: 17px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c3zk.png);
}
```

[Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uchrp/) (i added background-color:red; because the image wasn't loading.)

Hope it helps. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<a class="my-title" href="#">Search</a>
```

css

```
a.my-title { text-indent:-9999px }
```

**or**

html

```
<a class="my-title" title="Search" href="#"></a>
```

css

```
a.my-title { display:block;width:123px; all-your-styling:...; }
```

Screen reader will catch the **title** attribute from your anchor.