# Replace text inside a list with an image

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to replace text (link) inside a list with an image. This doesn't seem to work

my code:

HTML:

```
<div id = "headeranna"> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="annaklein">Vraag het aan Anna</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vraag het aan Anna</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#headeranna {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:410px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -90px;
    float:right;
}

#annaklein{
    display:block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background: url(small_anna.gif);
    text-indent: -9999px
}
```

This doesn't do anything at all, am I missing something?

Comment: you need to use javascript.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use javascript, any other way to fix this?

Comment: Use some kind of dynamic scripting language.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear, I can only use html and css

Comment: I think this should answer your question: [Hide Text Using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471510/hide-text-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

There can be different kind of problems:

- wrong url for the image
- too big image and it's left top corner is transparent or same as background
- etc...

I suggest you to use the background link this:

```
background: transparent url(small_anna.gif) top left no-repeat;
```

or at least try:

```
background: red; /* you can start with checking if you can see the background */
```

And maybe you should put your code to [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), there we can see your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this did not fix it though. I have removed the text from the list now and did it that way

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to use quotes

```
  background: url("small_anna.gif");
```

By the way...

An absolute positioned element will always compute float to value  "none". 
So the declaration in #headeranna   **float:right;** is not necessary.

Take care that the path for your image is ok in relation to your document

You can see this background working here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/mqwLK/)
(I modify some margin values just for the example target)

Comment: I guess you're right, however this isn't the problem because it does work for an image which isn't in a list.

Comment: Quotes aren't always needed when specifying background urls.  It works either way unless you need to escape quote characters in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your CSS

```
#annaklein{
list-style-type: none;
list-style-image:url("small_anna.gif");
width: 26px;
height: 26px;
text-indent: -9999px;}
```