# Special unicode/escape character(s) to hide text?

Tags: html, css, text, unicode

Does anyone know if there are special unicode delimeters to hide text from being displayed on the page in HTML? Something that you can place around text to make it not appear? Not like a comment or something. This could even work with the CSS content property.

Nevermind the reason why. It's just a browser hack that I'm trying to do.

Comment: If this existed, it would be a _horrifying_ security problem. It would be unsafe to copy-paste anything from the internet into your code, even just comments or words in a string.

Answer (score 4):

No, Unicode is about coding characters, not controlling whether characters are displayed or not. There are some control codes encoded as Unicode characters (“control characters”) but they deal with issues like line breaking, writing direction, and glyph selection, not issues like hiding text.

Even if there were Unicode characters that would hide text (and there aren’t), conforming implementations could ignore them. The Unicode Standard does not require support to all characters, or any characters in particular.

Answer (score 2):

This goes beyond the definition of what Unicode characters are able to do. When you mention that you want something to "place around text to make it not appear", this functionality belongs to the realm of mark-up. There are some control marks that affect the directionality of the following characters and are used for proper display of right-to-left text, but as far as I know there are no characters which affect other characters visibility. Probably the most creative usage of Unicode characters in such contexts is [Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work).

Anyway...there are various method to do this using CSS, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471510/hide-text-using-css).