# Hide text that doesn't have specific selector

Tags: css

Suprisingly I couldn't find an answer to this one anywhere - I might be using the wrong words...?!

Is there a possiblity to hide the word "English" from the following snippet with pure css? In terms of a `display:none`, so is doesn't take up any space:

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-language menu-item-language-current">
    <a href="#" onclick="return false">
        <img class="iclflag" src="/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/en.png" width="18" height="12" alt="English" title="English" />
        English
    </a>
</li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. There are many options to 'hide' text.

Comment: If the text would be in a span, I'd like to set the span to `display: none`. But it's not in a span. I could of course select the link `a`, but I want the image to stay and just the text to disappear. I'm basically looking for the selector for selecting plain text - if that exists...

Comment: Do you mean hiding and then making visible via a user input?

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471510/hide-text-using-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the font-size to zero.

```css
a {
    font-size:0;
}
```

```html
   <a href="#" onclick="return false">
        <img class="iclflag" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-18-12-10.jpg" width="18" height="12" alt="English" title="English" />
        English
    </a>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it still take space in the DOM?

Comment: What do you mean by "space" in the DOM? No page screen space but would it still be readable by screen readers...yep, absolutely.