# Data URI: Changing color & defining content area

Tags: css, svg, data-uri

I found [some icons](http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/home_720) on Flaticon.com to use them in the navigation menu of my blog. In this case I wanted to replace the text "Home" with a house icon using the Base64 code.

This is the current code that was used on my site:

```
.menu-item-36 {
  content: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAABHNC…ToDCG0DxpgvOsX4GsAgGyBKX8AAAAASUVORK5CYII5467651096249186f76b4680bd54615d');
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

I changed `background-image` to `content` in order to hide the original text 'Home' and replace it with the icon.

Now the problem: When I use the code above, the icon has a black color. I would like to use a white color instead. When I set the class to `color: #fff;` or `fill: #fff;` it doesn't work.

[image]

How can I this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the text, you should not change the background css property to content. I don't know iff you should even use content for anything else then the ::before and ::after psuedo elements.

But for your questions:

To hide text, you should use one of the possibilities given in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/471538/2012433

To make your image white, there is a hacky solution, namely using this css:

```
-webkit-filter: invert(100%);
        filter: invert(100%);
```

But better would be to download the image and edit it to white. Then get the base64 code at for example http://www.base64-image.de/

Finally when you set that image as background-image, the following css will fit it nicely in your menu:

```
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
```

Comment: Well you are right. The problem is that the second link you posted does not support for converting base64 to svg.. and turning it back into a base64 code. I made some research and found this site: http://vectorpaint.yaks.co.nz/ you can upload a svg and change its color. Only problem is that I am unable to turning the svg into a base64 code...

Comment: You can convert the svg to png format using this site: http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png and then convert it to base64 code, but I prefer to just use the svg image in most cases.