# How to target and hide a title with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to target a title, which is also `a title`. The word I want to hide is `contact` from the following html. There doesn't seem to be another way as even the ID is linked to the main menu so hiding it by ID would hide whole menu.

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

  <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-3530" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3530 dropdown">
      <a title="Contact" href="https://4309.co.uk/contact/">Contact</a>
      <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Perhaps I have explained this poorly. If you look in mobile in the top left corner[here](https://4309.co.uk/contact), drop the drop down menu by toggling the hamburger icon, you will see three letters `act,` the end of the word `contact` how to get rid of that? In desktop the whole word appears below the logo. It's an item with children, and I've tried using higher tier selectors and applying them to the ID, such as `ul li`, but this doesn't work. Hiding the ID will hide the parent and the children, when I need to separate it from its children and hide it individually.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the title attribute from displaying so that when you hover the item you do not see the tooltip message appear? Or are you trying to hide the entire `<a title="Contact">Contact` element? Or just the word "Contact" inside of the `<a>` element?

Comment: I just don't want the word `contact` to appear. Ideally hide the whole element but it's linked to the whole menu and i just want to hide the word. Could i do `id:nth-child(1)`or something? Hmmm

Comment: @Stackinnerflow you mean that you don't want the word "contact" in this link "https://4309.co.uk/contact/" to appear?

Comment: @zeniel. I mean i don't want it to appear in top left corner when dropdown menu is down, here in mobile https://4309.co.uk/contact

Comment: okay, so you don't want it to appear when browsed through mobile and the menu is hit right?

Comment: @zeniel Yes............

Comment: so do you have a media tag set?

Comment: What's that?....

Comment: lemme show you hold up

Comment: one more question do you have your contact title tag under, body or head tag?

Comment: It must be in my head....pretty sure

Comment: How about posting a [reprex]? In the mean time try accessing the `<a>` by using an attribute selector like `a[href="https://4309.co.uk/"] {...do some hiding stuff...}` in your CSS? [w3schools: CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: @ Rene nice try didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some clever ways to hide text using CSS, although that's not the most ideal approach. [This approach](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/) uses a clever combination of text indentation to achieve the end result. You could use the attribute selector to target any `<a>` tags where the title attribute is "Contact" as such:

```
a[title='Contact'] {
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

As referenced in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471510/hide-text-using-css), which can offer some more ideas as well. Notably:

```
a[title='Contact'] { color: transparent; }
```

Comment: See mobile https://4309.co.uk/contact top left in screen when you drop the menu

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to target the `a` element which has a `title` of `Contact`. In CSS, this can be done with the following selector:

```
a[title="Contact"]
```

Then, you need to hide the element. There are two options for doing this:

```
display: none;
```

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Here is a code snippet which demonstrates the first of these two methods (using the `display` property):

```css
a[title="Contact"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

  <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-3530" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3530 dropdown">
      <a title="Contact" href="https://4309.co.uk/contact/">Contact</a>
      <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

The bullet point is still there, so you can see that only the text `Contact` is being hidden, and not the `li` element. The CSS has targeted only the one element with that specific title.

Comment: I've tried but I've done what you said and word is still here in top left hand corner of mobile when you drop the menu. https://4309.co.uk/contact

Answer (score 0):

Okay I checked, the "contact" you're talking about is under a span tag and it's on a different base level, so Imma answer your question on a conceptual basis:

So in order to hide that contact from that dropdown menu, all you'd have to do is change that element's color to the background color so it's invisible and stop the link from working using like no hover effects and removing the link from CSS using a media query of course so that it doesn't affect when browsed from other devices than mobile here's how to do it

```
link.href = '';
```

leave it blank and you are all set, It won't show you that link anymore or none can click when using mobile

As per your question now:
you are seeing the "act" instead of "contact" because of no margin when in mobile view, so fix the margin first and then if you have access to the mainframe code,
use the methods I said above and it would work I promise

Comment: @Stackinnerflow And you might wanna reload your cache so if you are displaying it from Chrome, press Ctrl + Shift + R and if Safari then press Command + Option + R

Comment: Oh sorry i misunderstood. Media queries, yes, i know what that is. It doesn't work,

Comment: Not sure what `a cont` is?

Comment: its accessing cont class that is under the anchor tag

Comment: Tried your suggestion with css `a.cont ` didn't work. Nice ideas though.

Comment: @Stackinnerflow check this out, this should answer your problem on a conceptual level and fix your current problem, hope that helps :)

Comment: That's the thing that i can't select it with a attribute url because i have a fa-arrow-right with a link which leads to the page. Using `a [href="https: etc] {display:none;}`will hide this link.

Comment: If i could select it, then i would know what to do. But i can't separate it from its children.

Comment: I do but it's php and not sure where to find what's generating the html.

Comment: @Stackinnerflow include that in the question so someone who knows about it can help you out